Can someone assess this translation I did?
I translated an orthodox christian prayer that I originally found in english. Recently I started learning latin and this is my first real attempt at translating anything. I would like to receive some feedback about it, as well as suggestions about better options for vocabulary and word ordering. I am particularly doubtful about the choice for the verb expressing "that all men might be gathered unto thee", the verb "ocurro" in its reflexive subjunctive imperfect conjugation. Thank you!
Original: "O Christ our God, who at this hour didst stretch out Thy loving arms upon the Cross that all men might be gathered unto Thee, help us and save us who faithfully cry out unto Thee: Glory to Thee, O Lord".
Translation: "Christe Deus noster, qui in hac hora extendisti bracchia Tua misericordia in Cruce ut omnes homines occurrerent se in Te, auxiliare nos et salva nos qui fideliter clamamus ad Te: Gloria Tibi, Domine".


I am also rather doubtful about using occurrere reflexively; for one, because it's an intransitive verb, so that makes little sense. I would suggest congrego instead, which not only (to my theologically unsophisticated mind) seems particularly apt for the religious subject matter, but is often used reflexively and thus can simply be dropped into your sentence without changing anything else. It is also often used in the passive medially, somewhat as in your English source text (cf. Liv. 1, 10: congregabantur undique ad T. Tatium).

I do not think pronouns or the word crux ought to be capitalized in Latin, though Deus and Dominus certainly should.

There is nothing wrong with auxiliari in particular, but I think that adiuvare is more common for divine assistance.

Clamare is typically used with an acc. personae, as is inclamare, which you might also use. Also fitting would be acclamare + dative.



This is not an answer to your question, but with your indulgence I will post it anyway, because I suspect it might interest you.
Your English prayer is very reminiscent of this prayer from the Liturgia Horarum, feria quarta ad nonam:
Domine Iesu Christe, qui manus tuas in cruce ad salvandos homines extendisti, concede, ut actus nostri tibi reddantur accepti, et opus tuae redemptionis in mundo valeant declarare.
It's not identical to be sure, but it's close enough that I have to suspect a common origin. Perhaps it will inspire you in your own composition.
